# Android: Is it possible to force no screen overflow in a layout that contains a scrollview?

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I have a simple question for you: is it possible to force no screen overflow in a layout that contains a `ScrollView`?

For instance, if i have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">     
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">     
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If The `TableLayout` has many `TableRow` the `Scrollview` is being expanded up to the end of the screen and the lower `LinearLayout` is no more visible. Is it possible to force, without set height, `ScrollView` height in order to let enough space to display the lower `LinearLayout`?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply an `android:layout_weight` to the `ScrollView`; this way it will take up whatever space is not taken by the other elements.

In the adjustments below, the two `LinearLayout`s will take up enough space to accomodate their content, and the `ScrollView` will take up whatever is left:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This should be weighted height -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- This should be wrap_content height -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think you're missing the android:weightSum attribute, like i had in my original answer. without it, the xml may not work. also, shouldn't layout_height of the inner elements be "0dip" instead of "match_parent"?

Comment: @DavidT. The weight sum attribute is optional, especially if you're not assigning weights to all elements. And the height only has to be 0 for the item to which the weight is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your outer linear layout, set "android:layout_weight" to each element, and have the outer layer specify a "weightSum"

like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">     
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">     
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the "weightSum" and "layout_weight" specifies a ratio of how much of the screen should be used. in my example, the bottom and top each take 10% of the screen, leaving 80% as the middle scrollview (filled by tableview)

now, i believe you will also need to change the  to have the height be "match_parent", since u want that to take all 80% of the screen... double check that...

the other thing you have to change (depending on your version of SDK & editor) is for each inner element's "layout_height" to be "0dip" or else this mechanism may not work or you get an error

Comment: gah. sorry, the formatting is all messed up, but you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry but i can accept only one answer.. Your code is been useful for me as the other one.. Thank you David..

Comment: @user1709805 no worries :) if my answer was useful as well, would you please consider upvoting both of our answers? ( hit the up arrow to the left of my answer, it's right above the number 0 )